# Why does my Map class do not fetch any records in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to fetch AirLineData.csv file to determine number of flights in different year at a particular Airport. And for that map output file is not showing any records even though it is taking map input record as 10000.

This is my Mapper Class Function

```
    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text>
   {
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      {           
         try{
            String[] str = value.toString().split(",");  
            //String dummy_column = str[0]; //value
            int int_year = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);//key
            context.write(new IntWritable(int_year),new Text(str[0])); //key and vlaue
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
```

And This is my driver class method:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //conf.set("name", "value")
        //conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize", "134217728");
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Frequency count of flight");
        job.setJarByClass(FlightFrequency.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        //job.setCombinerClass(ReduceClass.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
```

And these are my results:

```
[bigcdac43211@ip-10-1-1-204 ~]$ hadoop jar myjar.jar AirData training/AirLineData.csv training/out8                                           
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
22/11/24 08:16:58 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-10-1-1-204.ap-south-1.compute.internal/10.1.1.204:8032
22/11/24 08:16:58 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execu
te your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
22/11/24 08:16:58 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /user/bigcdac43211/.staging/job_1663041244711_12176
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.syste
m-metrics-publisher.enabled
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1663041244711_12176
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1663041244711_12176
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-10-1-1-204.ap-south-1.compute.internal:6066/proxy/application_166304
1244711_12176/
22/11/24 08:16:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1663041244711_12176
22/11/24 08:17:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1663041244711_12176 running in uber mode : false
22/11/24 08:17:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
22/11/24 08:17:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
22/11/24 08:17:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
22/11/24 08:17:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1663041244711_12176 completed successfully
22/11/24 08:17:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 54
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=20
                FILE: Number of bytes written=445167
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=10585174
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=8
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Job Counters                                                                                                                          
                Launched map tasks=1                                                                                                          
                Launched reduce tasks=1                                                                                                       
                Rack-local map tasks=1                                                                                                        
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=4998                                                                      
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=3389                                                                   
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4998                                                                                   
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=3389                                                                                
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4998                                                                          
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=3389                                                                       
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=5117952                                                                    
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=3470336                                                                 
        Map-Reduce Framework                                                                                                                  
                Map input records=100000                                                                                                      
                Map output records=0                                                                                                          
                Map output bytes=0                                                                                                            
                Map output materialized bytes=16                                                                                              
                Input split bytes=127                                                                                                         
                Combine input records=0                                                                                                       
                Combine output records=0                                                                                                      
                Reduce input groups=0                                                                                                         
                Reduce shuffle bytes=16                                                                                                       
                Reduce input records=0                                                                                                        
                Reduce output records=0                                                                                                       
                Spilled Records=0                                                                                                             
                Shuffled Maps =1                                                                                                              
                Failed Shuffles=0                                                                                                             
                Merged Map outputs=1                                                                                                          
                GC time elapsed (ms)=175                                                                                                      
                CPU time spent (ms)=3850                                                                                                      
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=771170304                                                                                    
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=5179764736                                                                                    
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=883425280                                                                                  
                Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=581619712                                                                                    
                Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=2589802496                                                                                    
                Peak Reduce Physical memory (bytes)=189550592                                                                                 
                Peak Reduce Virtual memory (bytes)=2589962240                                                                                 
        Shuffle Errors                                                                                                                        
                BAD_ID=0                                                                                                                      
                CONNECTION=0                                                                                                                  
                IO_ERROR=0                                                                                                                    
                WRONG_LENGTH=0                                                                                                                
                WRONG_MAP=0                                                                                                                   
                WRONG_REDUCE=0                                                                                                                
        File Input Format Counters                                                                                                            
                Bytes Read=10585047                                                                                                           
        File Output Format Counters                                                                                                           
                Bytes Written=0
```

As You could see I am taking input but my map output record is 0:

```
Map-Reduce Framework                                                                                                                  
Map input records=100000                                                                                                      
Map output records=0
```

This are my sample data(I have only shown few rows here) and first two columns are ID,Year:

```
ARY04F1,2004,1,12,1,623,630,901,915,UA,462,N805UA,98,105,80,-14,-7,ORD,CLT,599,7,11,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
ARY06F48889,2006,1,17,2,1453,1500,1557,1608,US,2176,N752UW,64,68,38,-11,-7,DCA,LGA,214,3,23,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0
ARY08F85465,2008,1,4,5,2037,2015,2144,2120,WN,3743,N276WN,127,125,109,24,22,SLC,OAK,588,8,10,0,,0,0,0,12,0,12
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Your `context.write` line is never called if there's an exception.

Open `The url to track the job` and look at the mapper logs to check out if your exception line was really printed (note: you should use Slf4j to print, not System.out)

Not really clear why you need to parse the year to an integer. The reducer will happily accept a Text key that is the year

Comment: Thank you learned something new from your answer, but I don't have access to URL to track my job or the log files because I have a cloud access provided by my institution and has limited functionalities.

Comment: Then your institution has a poor setup, sorry. Any developer on their platform should be able to debug their own applications, not just blindly submit code that might not work... Cloud doesn't matter. But maybe this helps https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html